# Can I get a Windows XP-like application taskbar in OS X?

Tags: macos, taskbar

I'm looking for a Windows-like taskbar application switcher in OS X.

I'm mainly looking for a Windows XP-like taskbar, not the app-icon taskbar that Windows 7 has by default.

**Not**, I hasten to add, because I dislike the Apple Dock, but because it suits my workflow and use pattern better than a Dock-like system.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [iTaskbar](http://itaskbar.com).

> - Window-oriented
> - Start menu with application launcher
> - Lots of options including customizable styles
> - Global Shortcuts, Drag & Drop, Show Desktop, etc.
>
> [image]

Comment: Please read the following topic: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) – thank you!